# pythonをインストールしたけれど最新バージョンにならない

Tags: python, python3, windows

Windows 10 を使っていて、Pythonの最新バージョン (Python3.10.~) をインストールし、PATH も通したのですが、コマンドプロンプトで `python --version` を実行すると、"Python 2.7.14" と出てしまいます。

いくつかのサイトで調べても解決法が分からないので、質問させていただきました。
よろしければ、ご教授いただけると幸いです。

#### 試したこと

1. 設定の「アプリ実行エイリアス」で、python.exe と python3.exe をオフにする
2. `python --version` を実行

   実行結果

   ```
   'python3' は、内部コマンドまたは外部コマンド、
   操作可能なプログラムまたはバッチ ファイルとして認識されていません。
   ```
3. 環境変数にpython3のPATHを入れる。

Comment: 「Python 2.7.14」はご自身で以前にインストールしたものですか？ Python3のインストール後にPathを通した後はPCに再起動は試されましたか？

Comment: 既に誰かが`Python 2.7.14`を`Add Python 2.7 to PATH`インストールしていたのでは？ そのPCが貴方専用で`Python 2.7`が不要なら`Python 2.7`をアンインストールすれば良いでしょう。環境を変えられないなら、`Python 3.10`の起動は`Py`コマンド(2文字だけ)で試してみてください。(できるかどうかは`Py -V`を実行すれば分るでしょう) ちなみに`Python 3.10`のフォルダを`PATH`に入れても、`PATH`の頭の方に`Python 2.7`が登録されていればそちらが先に使われるので意味は無いですよ。

Comment: とりあえず、 `py -3.10 --version` で明示的に3.10を指定すると、正しくバージョンは表示されますか？

Comment: "py --version" と打つと、"Python 3.10.6"と一応出るのですが、これは最新バージョンが反映されているということでよろしいのでしょうか？また、Mac os では "python3 ～" でコマンドを使ってる感じですが、windowsではコマンドを使うときは "py" なのでしょうか？ os の違いで書き方も違うのかが気になりました。

Comment: 公式の説明 [4.8. Windows の Python ランチャ - 4. Windows で Python を使う](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/using/windows.html#python-launcher-for-windows) と他の人の詳しい解説記事 [Pythonランチャで複数のPython環境を使い分ける](https://astherier.com/blog/2020/07/usage-of-python-launcher/), [Pythonの複数バージョンの扱い方（Windowsの場合）](https://gammasoft.jp/python/python-version-management/) を参照してください。

Comment: 解決済みと思われますが御参考として，「コマンドのフルパス」を検索する方法についてです。普段は mac ですが，家人のPCをメンテする際に調べました。「コマンド プロンプト」では `>where python` ， 「PowerShell」では `> where.exe python` または（実行されるものに絞るなら） `> (gcm python).source` です。